# Get JSON response starting from string

Tags: android, json, api

I am calling an API and the response coming from the API is starting from a string without any curly bracket. The response is as follows:

```
 yourmessages{"status":1,"message":"List of Messages","data":[{"conversation_id":"8","last_message":"hello","mainid":"10"}]}
```

Here is what I was doing previously when the api response was starting from '{' but now the response starts with 'yourmessages'.

```
 JSONObject response_ = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONArray jsonArray = response_.getJSONArray("data");
```

How do I get to data array with the new response? Can anyone help please. Thanks

Comment: If the response will always look like that, and it is in string format, then truncate the your messages string and then you will be able to convert it using the logic you used before.

Comment: Asked backend team to remove that yourmessages text, its not standard response, otherwise replace yourmessages with empty text or take substring from first { to end of string.

Comment: Thanks alot I will ask him to remove it